# how to show list view record from sqlite into second listview on setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have created list view, what I want to do is that when user clicks on first list view the selected record For that Particular Field should show in second list view,

in my code I Just get the item position of the first list view and i pass Selected item of that list view into  my second Activity i dont know what i do next

so please give me the code/idea how to do this as I am new in android..

Here is My Code

MainActivity:(First List View)

```
    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
try {
    dbHelper.openDataBase();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

sqLiteDatabase=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
cursor=dbHelper.gettitles(sqLiteDatabase);

String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.TITLE };
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.title };
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.title_row,cursor,from,to);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         Cursor cursor =(Cursor) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
            String selectedItem = cursor.getString(0);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubcategoryActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("selectedItem", selectedItem);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

MainActivity Xmlcode:(Firstlistview)

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

Title_row.xml
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Second Activity:(Second List view)
listView2= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

```
    final String selectedData = intent.getStringExtra("selectedItem");
    dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
    try {
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sqLiteDatabase=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor=dbHelper.getsubcategory(sqLiteDatabase,selectedData);
    String[] from = new String[] { dbHelper.SUBCATEGORY };
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.subcategory };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.subcategory_row,cursor,from,to);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView2.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Subcategory Xml File:

```
 <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

subcategory_row.xml
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/subcategory"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Database CLass:

```
public Cursor gettitles(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = db.query(true, "record", new String[]{TITLE,ITEMNO + " as _id"}, null, null, TITLE, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

     public Cursor getsubcategory(SQLiteDatabase db,String sub)
    {
        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor;
        cursor = db.query("record",new String[]{SUBCATEGORY},TITLE + "=" +sub,null,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Logcat:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FOOD": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT subcategory FROM record WHERE title=GENERAL FOOD TIPS
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1448)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1295)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1166)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1334)
        at com.example.aeiltech.sidd.SqlLiteDbHelper.getsubcategory(SqlLiteDbHelper.java:118)
        at com.example.aeiltech.sidd.SubcategoryActivity.onCreate(SubcategoryActivity.java:38)
```

Comment: actually what is your dataset? can you provide the code for SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: Its just a Simple TextView

Comment: what is that "to" and "from"?

Comment: I get the title column name in database and pass that into another Activity in that activity i just have a simple Textview

Comment: @HariKrishnan Check My Updated COde

Comment: [I need Like this but i want to get it from Database][1] @HariKrishnan


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i5OAB.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want to do, however i see two Errors in your code that may help solve the problem. If they don't, please provide a better understandable problem description.

1. In the onItemClickListener you are trying to cast the item from the List to a String. However the Method `getItemAtPosition(position)` will pass to the function `getItem(position)` of the adapter, which in your case will return a Cursor. You cannot cast a Cursor to a String. Therefore your code at this position should look something like this:

   ```
   Cursor cursor =(Cursor) (listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
   String selectedItem = cursor.getString(0);
   ```
2. In your second list view you have the following function call:

   ```
   cursor=dbHelper.getsubcategory(sqLiteDatabase,sub);
   ```

   However i don't see where you define `sub`. My best guess after reading your code is that `sub` should be the selected title in the first list view. Therefore this call should look like this:

   ```
   cursor=dbHelper.getsubcategory(sqLiteDatabase,selectedData);
   ```

Comment: Thanks But i am Looking for like this 
 
[I need Like this but i want to get it from Database][1] : i.stack.imgur.com/i5OAB.png

Comment: in my Database i have Colum names like Title,Subcategory and Details...I am trying to display all my columns names in listview..first i display My Title column names..now i am trying to display my Subcategory column name..the subcategory will display based on the selection of Title @findsul

Comment: After Updated Your Code my App Was Crash and it says java.lang.NullPointerException on Subcategoryclass @findsul

Comment: I Updated My Code Plz Check @findsul

Comment: After seeing your picture i see that i understood your problem right :)

In which line is the NullPointerException? Is it here: final String selectedData = intent.getStringExtra("selectedItem");
you have to initialize intent like that: Intent intent = getIntent();

Comment: Thanks A Lot :) Now i have a New Error in Database class plz Check My Logcat @findsul

Comment: I want to Display Subcategory Fields based on the selection of Titles @findsun

Comment: The title of your subcategory contains spaces, therefore you have to set it in the according quotation marks when querying the db.

Comment: Thanks A Lot ji Thank U Sooo Much...ur ULTIMATE :)